# Ubuntu GRUB RESCUE mode - screwed up partitions - attempted t look for boot folder with no luck

Tags: partitioning, grubrescue

So, I'm a beginner programmer and I was going a bit into depth in Android programming, so because of what I wanted to do, Ubuntu was my best option which I installed alongside with Windows 10.

It was working perfectly fine, both OSs' and didn't have problem with neither of them. Because I had a file on my Windows partition, I thought it'd be a excellent idea to create a new partition on my disk, kind of a 'virtual memory stick' if I can call it that, So I can use (modify it) on both OS without any problems.

My main intention was to create a 128 MB FAT32 partition from a unallocated partition, but initially I accidental did a NTFS one, that for some reason created two, and it had problems with formatting them etc.

So when I created my wanted one, all working perfectly fine, and I was able to paste my phone's firmware on it (a .tar.md5 file).

After that I rebooted my PC and when it booted, it went into GRUB RESCUE mode. I've done all possible research on it, but when I do a list of the disk, I've got hd0 and then (hd0, msdos4) through to msdos1, out of which none contain the boot folder.

I'd like to get help fixing this with minimal data loss.

Also I was thinking if it'd be a good idea cloning only the Windows partition (alongside system reserved) but I don't have the equipment to do this right now.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Note that generlly better to use NTFS as FAT32 does not allow files over 4GB and has no journal for repair. FAT32 is ok for small partitions. Also With Windows 8 or 10  you must have Windows fast start up or hibernation off or all Windows type partitions are hibernated.

Comment: @oldfred so should I download the boot-repair, place it on my USB stick, which at the same time has a Ubuntu installation, then boot from USB, go to try Ubuntu, and run the program there?

Comment: No, as  mentioned above use the procedure to boot Ubuntu live installer and add ppa. Then you are running from Ubuntu live. Every time you reboot you would have to re-install, but I do not think Boot-Repair's own live ISO has been updated and was based on Lubuntu 14.04, so may not support a lot of newer systems.